# Alternate Statements of System.out.println()

Tags: java, printing

Can anybody please help me by providing different ways of printing other than System.out.println() statement in Java?

Comment: But still printing to stdout? Why are you trying to avoid System.out.println?

Comment: I just want to learn the different ways.Is it possible to use a file?

Comment: Also,can't i use a properties file?

Comment: You can read/write to a file (including properties files) but that is an unrelated question really.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
....
public class example{

static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.class);

.....
public void test(){
 String hello ="Hello World";
 log.trace(hello);
}
....
}

output will be :
TRACE:(<classname>){2011-10-38-06:644} Hello World 2011-05-10 08:38:06,644
```

Comment: It should be noted that, for this to work, your project has a dependency on Log4j, and `log4j.properties` has to be properly configured.

Comment: you must add log4j-1.2.14.jar to your project if you can't find this jar file, type your email here i will send it to your email

Answer (score 4):

This may help you.

```
import java.io.*;
class Redirection {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        PrintStream pos = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("applic.log"));

        PrintStream oldstream=System.out;
        System.out.println("Message 1 appears on console");
        System.setOut(pos);                 
        System.out.println("Message 2 appears on file"); 
        System.out.println("Message 3 appears on file");
        System.out.println("Message 4 appears on file");
        System.setOut(oldstream);
        System.out.println("Message 5 appears on console");
        System.out.println("Message 6 appears on console");        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternate printing methods:

```
System.out.print("message\r\n");
System.out.printf("%s %d", "message" , 101); // Since 1.5
```

You can also use regular IO File operations by using special files based on the platform to output stuff on the console:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("con"); // Windows
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("/dev/tty"); // *nix

pw.println("op");
```

Answer (score 2):

System.err.println() for printing on console. or create your own printstream object and then print to file, database or console.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following alternatives:

1.

```
System.err.print("Custom Error Message");
```

2.

```
System.console().writer().println("Hello World");
```

3.

```
System.out.write("www.stackoverflow.com \n".getBytes());
```

4.

```
System.out.format("%s", "www.stackoverflow.com \n");
```

5.

```
PrintStream myout = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out));
myout.print("www.stackoverflow.com \n");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it in eclipse by placing a mouse on the word a pop-up window will appear scroll down and select `JAVA.LANG.SYSTEM` .It will fix the problem and your code will run.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the code `System.out.printf();`